# how to dynamically set default value for those columns to 'NULL' in table 1 if exists in table 2 in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have `profile` and `exclusion` table in Snowflake and want to extract `profile_id` and `profile_name` as they are, while extracting `transaction_count` as `'null'` as this column exists in exclusion table.

I want to do this dynamically for all columns in the profile table as columns names for profile table in `exclusion` table will change as per business requirement.

*Example tables:*

**Profile:**

| profile_id | profile_name | transaction_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | priya | 3 |

**Exclusion:**

| table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| profile | transaction_count |

***Is this possible to do in SQL? Or in a stored procedure?***

Answer (score 1):

You can build more dynamically your update sql stmt using anonymous block  , right now I'm getting all columns from Information schema  of table and using that to build column list .Use same column list for updating in TBL profile. In case if you want to your own table "Exclusion' which hold column list , simple change to you select query and makes work. Below is block of code:

```
    execute immediate $$
      declare
        accumulator varchar default '';
        res1 RESULTSET default (Select column_name   from "LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" where table_schema='PUBLIC' and table_name='PROFILE' );  
        cur1 CURSOR for res1;     
        upd_stmt varchar;
      begin
        for row_variable in cur1 do
          accumulator := row_variable.column_name||'=NULL'||','||accumulator;
        end for;
        accumulator:=RTRIM(accumulator,',');
        upd_stmt:= 'update "LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG"."PUBLIC"."PROFILE" set '|| accumulator||';';
        execute immediate  :upd_stmt;
         return upd_stmt;
      end;
    $$;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anand . I want to use this block of code for all the tables, is there a way to bind table name as parameter inside a stored procedure

Comment: @Priya Yes you can.. but it shouldn't be anonymous block and it  should be named proc. You need to go with new request and place some sample data as part of request someone will help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the excluded columns and convert to an array, then, you can cast each field to NULL if the field name appears in that array.

> Note: I realized, as I began solving, that my solution is verbose and not ideal. I'm assuming there's a better method, perhaps with `JOINS` or with a `UDF`. Leaving my answer here, because it does work, until someone replaces with a better solution.

Create a CTE for exclude columns and apply to query of your business table:

```sql
WITH EXCLUDE(EXCLUDE_COLUMNS) AS (
    SELECT
        TO_ARRAY(column_name) AS EXCLUDE_COLUMNS
    FROM
        exclusion
)
-- Now make your query
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN 
           'profile_id' IN EXCLUDE.EXCLUDE_COLUMNS
       THEN
           profile_id
       ELSE NULL
    END AS profile_id,
    ....  -- Continue for each column
FROM
    profile
```

Comment: This will hit performance as most of my table has more than 200 columns

Comment: Ahh, bummer. Curious to see other answers here – this is indeed a difficult issue. @JangyasmitaPriyadarshini

Comment: I think your req. could work well with  above anonymous block which I given and you can leverage that.